# AngularJS updating form with select and passing parameters into controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-ng-options

I have a pretty simple itemController which contains an array of items (in actuality, these are obtained from an API). I want to then call the API again to get the subsections based on what is selected from the itemForm.item select (i.e., get all subsections for itemForm.item.id).

When I select Item1 (id=1), I want to update the form to include the subsections for that item.id. The problem I am having is how exactly to pass the itemForm.item.id into the sectionController. As you can see below, I tried it with $attrs, but this ends up passing in a string of "{{itemForm.item.id}}" instead of the actual value.

I am new to Angular and am quite possibly going about this wholly the wrong way, so please let me know if I am totally off base in my approach.

## Javascript

```
angular.module('app').controller('itemController', function(){
this.items = [
  {
   "id": 1, 
   "name": "Item1"
  }, 
  {
   "id": 2, 
   "name": "Item2"
  }, 
  {
   "id": 3, 
   "name": "Item3"
  }
];
}];

angular.module('app').controller('sectionController', 
['SectionService', '$attrs',
function(SectionService, $attrs){
var store = this;

SectionService.getSections($attrs.id)
    .then(function(data) {
        store.sections = data;
    }, function(error) {
        // promise rejected
        console.log(error);
    });

}]);
```

## HTML

```
<div class="form-group" ng-controller="itemController as item">
    <select ng-model="itemForm.item" ng-options="item as item.name for item in item.items track by item.id" required>
    </select>

    <!-- this is just a test to try to get the behavior to work correctly -->
    <div ng-controller="sectionController as section" id="{{$itemForm.item}}">
        <p ng-repeat="section in section.sections">{{section.name}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The SectionService is a factory which simply calls the API and returns a JSON array such as this for a particular itemID (itemID=1 in this case):

```
[
  {
    "name": "Section1", 
    "itemID": 1, 
    "sectionID": 1
  }, 
  {
    "name": "Section2", 
    "itemID": 1, 
    "sectionID": 2
  }, 
  {
    "name": "Section3", 
    "itemID": 1, 
    "sectionID": 3
  }, 
  {
    "name": "Section4", 
    "itemID": 1, 
    "sectionID": 4
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

SectionService is only getting called once, when sectionController is being loaded for the first time.

You need to use $scope.$watch to observe changes to $attrs.id if you want it to call SectionService every time the value for itemForm.item changes:

```
angular.module('app').controller('sectionController', 
['SectionService', '$attrs', '$scope',
function(SectionService, $attrs, $scope){
var store = this;

$scope.$watch(
  function(){ return $attrs.id; },
  function(){
     if($attrs.id){
        SectionService.getSections($attrs.id)
           .then(function(data) {
               store.sections = data;
        }, function(error) {
           // promise rejected
           console.log(error);
        });
     }
  }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you **must not** use `as` expression with the `track by`, you should use only one of them.

From [**docs**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#-select-as-and-track-by-):

> Be careful when using select as and track by in the same expression.

I'd suggest you to use like this:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="itemForm.item" ng-options="item.name for item in item.items track by item.id" ng-change="item.change(itemForm.item.id)" required>
```

Well, to achieve what you want, you have to do some things:

1. Use [**`ngChange`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive to get the `id` of the item `selected` in your parent `controller`:

```
ng-change="item.change(itemForm.item.id)"
```

2. *Inject* the `$scope` in both `controllers`;
3. Use the `$broadcast` to send `data` to the child `controller`

```
$scope.$broadcast('id', id);
```

4. Use `$on` to receive the data from the parent `controller`:

```
$scope.$on('id', function(event, id) {
  ...
});
```

Here's a *complete* **example**:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('itemController', itemController)
  .controller('sectionController', sectionController)
  .factory('SectionService', SectionService);

  sectionController.$inject = ['$scope'];
  
  function itemController($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.change = change;
    vm.items = [  
       {  
          "id":1,
          "name":"Item1"
       },
       {  
          "id":2,
          "name":"Item2"
       },
       {  
          "id":3,
          "name":"Item3"
       }
    ];
  
    function change(id) {
      // send data to child controller
      $scope.$broadcast('id', id);
    }
  }
  
  sectionController.$inject = ['SectionService', '$scope'];
  
  function sectionController(SectionService, $scope) {
    var store = this;
    var id = 1;
    // It's only to work here...
    var fakeData = [  
       {  
          "name":"Section1",
          "itemID":1,
          "sectionID":1
       },
       {  
          "name":"Section2",
          "itemID":1,
          "sectionID":2
       },
       {  
          "name":"Section3",
          "itemID":1,
          "sectionID":3
       },
       {  
          "name":"Section4",
          "itemID":1,
          "sectionID":4
       }
    ];
    
    function getSuccess(response) {
      // store.sections = response.data; <- it should be uncommented in your real application
      store.sections = fakeData;
    }
  
    function getError(response) {
      console.log(response);
    }
  
    // get the broadcast
    $scope.$on('id', function(event, id) {
      if (!id) return;
      getSuccess();
      /*SectionService.getSections(id)
        .then(getSuccess)
        .catch(getError); <- it should be uncommented in your real application */
    })
  }
  
  SectionService.$inject = ['$http'];
  
  function SectionService($http) {
    var factory = {
      getSections: getSections
    }
  
    return factory;
  
    function getSections(id) {
      //return $http.get('url' + id); <- it should be uncommented in your real application
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="form-group" ng-controller="itemController as item">
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="itemForm.item" ng-options="item.name for item in item.items track by item.id" ng-change="item.change(itemForm.item.id)" required>
      <option value="" label="Select item" hidden>
    </select>
    <hr>
    <div ng-controller="sectionController as section">
      <p ng-repeat="section in section.sections" ng-bind="section.name"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Please, **note** that I comment the parts that couldn't work **here** in snippet, but it should work in your real application.

I'd also recommend you to check this [**tutorial**](https://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/).